# snap-store giving error: Failed to load module "appmenu-gtk-module"

Tags: 20.04

snap-store is not showing apps in categories and not showing installed apps.
Running `snap-store` command gives this error:

```
08:51:26:0240 Gtk Failed to load module "appmenu-gtk-module"
```

[image]

What should I do now? I already tried:

```
sudo apt install appmenu-gtk2-module appmenu-gtk3-module
```